# Sage: Iterate over increasing sequences

Tags: sequence, sage

I have a problem that I am unwilling to believe hasn't been solved before in Sage.

Given a pair of integers *(d,n)* as input, I'd like to receive a list (or set, or whatever) of all **nondecreasing** sequences of length *d* all of whose entries are no greater than *n*.

Similarly, I'd like another function which returns all **strictly increasing** sequences of length *d* whose entries are no greater than *n*.

For example, for *d = 2* *n=3*, I'd receive the output:

[[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]

or

[[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,2], [2,3], [3,3]]

depending on whether I'm using increasing or nondecreasing.

Does anyone know of such a function?

**Edit** Of course, if there is such a method for nonincreasing or decreasing sequences, I can modify that to fit my purposes. Just something to iterate over sequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be solved by using the class "UnorderedTuples" described here:

> http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/tuple.html

To return all all nondecreasing sequences with entries between 0 and n-1 of length d, you may type:

```
UnorderedTuples(range(n),d)
```

This returns the nondecreasing sequence as a list. I needed an immutable object (because the sequences would become keys of a dictionary). So I used the "tuple" method to turn the lists into tuples:

```
immutables = []
for s in UnorderedTuples(range(n),d):
    immutables.append(tuple(s))
return immutables
```

And I also wrote a method which picks out only the increasing sequences:

```
def isIncreasing(list):
    for i in range(len(list) - 1):
        if list[i] >= list[i+1]:
            return false
    return true
```

The method that returns only strictly increasing sequences would look like

```
immutables = []
for s in UnorderedTuples(range(n),d):
    if isIncreasing(s):
        immutables.append(tuple(s))
return immutables
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed this algorithm too and I finally managed to write one today. I will share the code here, but I only started to learn coding last week, so it is not pretty.

**Idea** Input=(r,d). Step 1) Create a class "ListAndPosition" that has a list L of arrays Integer[r+1]'s, and an integer q between 0 and r. Step 2) Create a method that receives a ListAndPosition (L,q) and screens sequentially the arrays in L checking if the integer at position q is less than the one at position q+1, if so, it adds a new array at the bottom of the list with that entry ++. When done, the Method calls itself again with the new list and q-1 as input.

The code for Step 1)

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListAndPosition {
    public static Integer r=5;

```
public final ArrayList<Integer[]> L;
public int q;

public ListAndPosition(ArrayList<Integer[]> L, int q) {
    this.L = L;
    this.q = q;
}
public ArrayList<Integer[]> getList(){
    return L;
}
public int getPosition() {
    return q;
}
public void decreasePosition() {
    q--;
}
public void showList() {
    for(int i=0;i<L.size();i++){
        for(int j=0; j<r+1 ; j++){
            System.out.print(""+L.get(i)[j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

}

The code for Step 2)

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NonDecreasingSeqs {

```
public static Integer r=5;
public static Integer d=3;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Creating the first array

    Integer[] firstArray;
    firstArray = new Integer[r+1];
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
        firstArray[i] = 0;
    }
    firstArray[r] = d; 

    //Creating the starting listAndDim
    ArrayList<Integer[]> L = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    L.add(firstArray);

    ListAndPosition Lq = new ListAndPosition(L,r-1);

    System.out.println(""+nonDecSeqs(Lq).size());

}

public static ArrayList<Integer[]> nonDecSeqs(ListAndPosition Lq){

    int iterations = r-1-Lq.getPosition();
    System.out.println("How many arrays in the list after "+iterations+" iterations? "+Lq.getList().size());

    System.out.print("Should we stop the iteration?");

    if(0<Lq.getPosition()){         
        System.out.println(" No, position = "+Lq.getPosition());

        for(int i=0;i<Lq.getList().size();i++){
            //Showing particular array
            System.out.println("Array of L #"+i+":");
            for(int j=0;j<r+1;j++){
                System.out.print(""+Lq.getList().get(i)[j]);
            }

            System.out.print("\nCan it be modified at position "+Lq.getPosition()+"?");

            if(Lq.getList().get(i)[Lq.getPosition()]<Lq.getList().get(i)[Lq.getPosition()+1]){
                System.out.println(" Yes, "+Lq.getList().get(i)[Lq.getPosition()]+"<"+Lq.getList().get(i)[Lq.getPosition()+1]);

                {
                    Integer[] tempArray = new Integer[r+1];
                    for(int j=0;j<r+1;j++){
                        if(j==Lq.getPosition()){
                            tempArray[j] = new Integer(Lq.getList().get(i)[j])+1;
                        }
                        else{
                            tempArray[j] = new Integer(Lq.getList().get(i)[j]); 
                        }
                    }
                    Lq.getList().add(tempArray);
                }
                System.out.println("New list");Lq.showList();   
            }

            else{
                System.out.println(" No, "+Lq.getList().get(i)[Lq.getPosition()]+"="+Lq.getList().get(i)[Lq.getPosition()+1]);
            }   
        }
        System.out.print("Old position = "+Lq.getPosition());
        Lq.decreasePosition();
        System.out.println(", new position = "+Lq.getPosition());

        nonDecSeqs(Lq);
    }
    else{ 
        System.out.println(" Yes, position = "+Lq.getPosition());
        }
    return Lq.getList();
}
```

}

Remark: I needed my sequences to start at 0 and end at d.

Comment: Thanks. I've actually found a class "Tuples" which seems to solve the problem. I'll put my solution in an answer just in case it helps you or anyone else.

Comment: (To be clear, the class Tuples is in Sage, which is the language to which my question refers.)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a very good answer to your question.  But you could, in principle, use [`Partitions`](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/partition.html#sage.combinat.partition.Partitions) and the `max_slope=-1` argument.  Messing around with filtering lists of `IntegerVectors` sounds equally inefficient and depressing for other reasons.

If this has a canonical name, it might be in the list of sage-combinat functionality, and there is even a base class you could perhaps use for [integer lists](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/integer_lists/base.html), which is basically what you are asking about.  Maybe you could actually get what you want using [`IntegerListsLex`](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/integer_lists/invlex.html#sage.combinat.integer_lists.invlex.IntegerListsLex)?  Hope this proves helpful.